# Error while trying to run project MSVSMON.exe VB.Net VS 2012

Tags: .net, vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I have problem to run debug in VS 2012 VB.NET
last change, i go to Properties and i change target framework.
initially i use Net Framework 4.5 and can run debugging, but if i change to other Framework and start debugging, VS give warning message like this
[image]

and i can't run debugging

and if i change to Net Framework 4.5 again, VS keep give same warning message anyone can help me? thanks :(

Comment: MSVSMON is the remote debugger, it will be used when you remove the jitter forcing and let your program run in 64-bit mode.  Required because VS is a 32-bit process.  Having trouble talking to it is an environmental problem, anti-malware usually has something to do with that.  Disable it and try again.

Comment: hmmm , my visual studio maybe version 32bit and my computer is 64bit. any suggestion without install new VS 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any form of pc protection? The free version of Zone Alarm firewall causes this error a lot.

If this isn't the problem, then check the filepath to msvmon and any permissions set on it.

Comment: No, that should be fine. I would check the filepath for the .exe and make sure it is in the right folder

Comment: how to check filepath? at VS i can't find the filepath, but if i search in my Program Files x86 Microsoft Visual Studio 11, i get filepath in here

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86 and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64